# PayPal Express Checkout without logging in

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Is it possible to use Paypal express checkout without signing in even if the user has a Paypal account present?

We have noticed that some folks forget their credentials and don't want to login to Paypal, thus causing us to lose their donation. The Account optional setting seems to still require users, who have a Paypal account linked to the provided email, to sign in even if they would like to pay from the checkout page.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: Paypal provide an optional guest checkout. Please check this https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/express-checkout#overview

Answer (score 0):

Paypal provide optional guest checkout. https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/express-checkout#overview

Answer (score 0):

Guest Checkout would allow people to use a credit card without signing in or creating an account, but the checkout would still take place in PayPal hosted pages.

If you'd like to process credit cards directly on your site you could use Payments Pro, the REST API, or Braintree.  The difference is really just the technical details in integrating it, so your developer could choose which method would work best for your setup, and then you could create that account and integrate it accordingly.

If you're already using and are familiar with PayPal in general I would recommend going with Payments Pro.  It typically costs $30/mo, but if you [contact me directly](https://www.angelleye.com/contact-us/) I can help you to get that fee waived.

You would also need to make sure your site has an SSL installed and can run from https:// correctly.

Once those things are in place it's just a matter of integrating Payments Pro into your current setup, which depending on what that is, there are a number of different ways that could be done.  I would need more detail to be able to help you more specifically with integration.